# Core Data fetch one record that has two matching fields

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to find a record that matches two fields in my entity. Below, I have my code that searches for Company only. How do I add AND Employee Number?

```
func userAcctExists(CompanyOffice: String, EmployNo: String) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserAccountMO>(entityName: "UserAccountTbl")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "companyOffice == %@", CompanyOffice)

    let res = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return res.count > 0 ? true : false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please name variables and parameter labels with starting lowercase letter.

A predicate can have multiple conditions *`AND`ed* and *`OR`ed*

And `res.count > 0 ? true : false` can be replaced just with `!res.isEmpty`

```
func userAcctExists(companyOffice: String, employNo: String) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserAccountMO>(entityName: "UserAccountTbl")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "companyOffice == %@ AND employNo == %@", companyOffice, employNo)

    let res = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return !res.isEmpty
}
```

`AND` and `&&` as well as `OR` and `||` are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.1**

```
func userAcctExists(CompanyOffice: String, EmployNo: String) -> Bool {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserAccountMO>(entityName: "UserAccountTbl")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "companyOffice == %@ && employNo == %@", CompanyOffice, employNo)

        let res = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return res.count > 0 ? true : false
    }
```

`&&` and `AND` well as `||` and `OR` are synonyms.